# Unable to create extent reports in Java

Tags: java, testng, extentreports

HI I am unable to get the reports. I am not facing any kind of errors but reports are not generating.

public class Listners extends TestListenerAdapter{

```
public ExtentHtmlReporter htmlReporter;
public ExtentReports extent;
public ExtentTest test;

public void onStart (ITestContext testContext)
{
    htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/test-output/myReport.html");
    htmlReporter.config().setDocumentTitle("Automation Report");
    htmlReporter.config().setReportName("Rest API Testing Report");

    extent = new ExtentReports();

public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult testResult)
{
    test = extent.createTest(testResult.getName());
    test.log(Status.PASS, "Test Case Pass is --" +testResult.getName());
}
public void onTestFailure(ITestResult testResult)
{
    test = extent.createTest(testResult.getName());
    test.log(Status.FAIL, "Test Case Failed is --" +testResult.getName());
    test.log(Status.FAIL, "Test Case Failed is --" +testResult.getThrowable());
}
public void onTestSkipped(ITestResult testResult)
{
    test = extent.createTest(testResult.getName());
    test.log(Status.SKIP, "Test Case Skipped is --" +testResult.getName());
}
public void onTestFlush(ITestContext testContext)
{
    extent.flush();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question, you just should marked your test class by @Listeners annotation and put your Listener class into this annotation.

```
     @Listeners([your listener class name].class)
     public void [your test class name] {
       /*
       *
       * some tests
       *
       */
     }
```

Comment: I am still not able to get the reports